# Close unresponsive window without waiting for "... is not responding" dialog

Tags: windows-7, windows, window, unresponsive

Once a window becomes unresponsive to input (mouse clicks), OS first waits 10 seconds, then window contents lighten, and a dialog appears:

> ... is not responding
>
> If you close the program, you might lose information.

With these options to choose from:

> Close the program
>
> Wait for the program to respond

A reason for windows to became unresponsive is not a problem I need to address. Applications work as expected, I just don't need to wait for them to complete what they are doing.

Killing a task with task manager is not a good way because this takes roughly the same time at least.

I would like to have options to close a window faster without waiting several seconds for this routine.

Is there a way to lower response timeout to, say, 2 seconds?

Is there a third-party utility to kill currently active window with a shortcut, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>?

Comment: Usually you could just click a close button a couple of times and Windows will ask you about closing an unresponsive application.

Comment: When a window is unresponsive, it seems that it doesn't matter if it's close button or any other part of the window that is clicked, This takes several seconds of waiting and clicking for it to show the dialog.

Comment: Well, I've just tried it myself. It takes about 5 seconds for me when Windows allowed to close an unresponsive application with the close button. And this seems like an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586029/how-to-extend-the-app-timeout-in-win-7

Comment: @montonero Thanks for the hint, I'll try HungAppTimeOut, it looks like what I'm looking for (for the first part of the question).